# Changing mouse size with mouse wheel up/down event

Tags: c#

If one of my buttons is selected and the mouse wheel is activated then its size should change according to the mouse wheel action.
If the mouse wheel goes up the size of my button should increase by 2.
If the mouse wheel goes down the size of my button should decrease by 2.

I'm trying something like this:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            btn = c as Button;
            {
                if (btn == null)
                    continue;

               c.MouseWheel += c_MouseWheel;


            }
        }
    }
    private void c_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;
        if (tabControl != null)
        {
            if (e.Delta < 0)
            {

                tabControl.Size = new Size(-2, -2);
            }
            else
            {

                tabControl.Size = new Size(+2, +2);
            }
```

Unfortunately my code does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now solved:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            btn = c as Button;
            {
                if (btn == null)
                    continue;

               c.MouseWheel += c_MouseWheel;


            }
        }
    }
    private void c_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ss = sender as Button;
        TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;
        int y = ss.Size.Width;
        int x = ss.Size.Height;

            if (e.Delta < 0)
            {

                ss.Size = new Size(y+2, x+2);
            }
            else
            {

                ss.Size = new Size(y-2, x-2);
            }
```